# Iterate key based name values and form the desired output using terraform

Tags: json, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

Iwant to extract key  based values as item1a and item2b .Can it be possible that How can we fetch and form the key values from the following data USING.   Terraform in local block.
Example input:

```
   Region1 :{
      Zone1a :{
       Item1a:{
         Var3: "samplevalue1"
         }
       Item2b:{
         Var4: "SAMPLEvalue2"
        }
       }

       Zone1b:{
       Item1a:{
         Var6: "sanplevLue3"
         Var7: "samplevalue4"
        }
       Item2b:{
         Var8: "SAMPLEvalue5"
         }
        }
       }
```

}

```
to the following required op
Example Output:

  Data1:{
   Itrm1a:{
      Var3: "samplevalue1"
      Var6: "samplevLue3"
      Var7: "samplevalue4"
       }
   Item2b:{
      Var4: "SAMPLEvalue2"
      Var8: "SAMPLEvalue5"
       }
      }
```

I want to produce above output from the following input.i have a json data here.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide TF code that you tried to solve the issue, and explain why it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure someone else will be able to simplify this but when i first looked at this i thought it would be an easy problem but took me about an hour to get it into the format you mention. probably is some refactoring that can clean this up.

```
locals {
  Region1 = {
    Zone1a : {
      Item1a : {
        Var3 : "samplevalue1"
      }
      Item2b : {
        Var4 : "SAMPLEvalue2"
      }
    }

    Zone1b : {
      Item1a : {
        Var6 : "sanplevLue3"
        Var7 : "samplevalue4"
      }
      Item2b : {
        Var8 : "SAMPLEvalue5"
      }
    }
  }

  # get a list of each item map
  items = concat([
  for zone, items in local.Region1: [
    for item, var in items: { (item): var} ]
  ]...)
  # group vars into the same item key
  data1 = {for item in local.items: keys(item)[0]=>values(item)...}
  # flatten the vars and merge them
  data2 = {for k, v in local.data1: k => merge(flatten(v)...)}
}

output "data2" {
  value = local.data2
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Outputs:

data2 = {
  "Item1a" = {
    "Var3" = "samplevalue1"
    "Var6" = "sanplevLue3"
    "Var7" = "samplevalue4"
  }
  "Item2b" = {
    "Var4" = "SAMPLEvalue2"
    "Var8" = "SAMPLEvalue5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris I tried only merge and loop which causes lot of issues, the above  works.